# Can I make a new post that combines other posts/questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Suppose that there is a topic that has different aspects and each aspect was discussed in a separate question, can I post a new question with all the information from other posts all together in my post? It will serve as one place to look for all the aspects instead of jumping to 10 different links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; that's not really a question, so it shouldn't be posted as one.

However, it sounds like that comprehensive wrap-up might be an interesting post for the site blog — you should check with @rfusca about that.

Comment: how can I check with him?

Comment: @Akram He is in the [photo chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14/photography) approximately 24 hours a day. :)

Comment: Pop in the chat room and let me know the details of what you're thinking if you like.  I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like what the tags are supposed to do, so it mightn't be a good thing to do.